# Call .exe from batch file with variable path containing spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to launch a windows executable from a batch file where the path to the executable is stored in a variable.

```sh
@echo off

set qtpath=C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin
set execpath=%qtpath%\windeployqt.exe

echo %execpath%

%execpath% --someparams
```

Unfortunately executing my script throws an error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Looks like somehow the string gets terminated at the space in `Program Files`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should change your code to this:

```
@echo off

set "qtpath=C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin"
set "execpath=%qtpath%\windeployqt.exe"

echo "%execpath%"

"%execpath%" --someparams
```

The <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, like also <kbd>TAB</kbd>, `,`, `;`, `=`, <kbd>VTAB</kbd> (vertical tabulator, ASCII `0x0B`), <kbd>FF</kbd> (form-feed, ASCII `0x0C`) and <kbd>NBSP</kbd> (non-break space, ASCII `0xFF`) constitute [token separators](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in the command prompt `cmd`. To escape tokenisation enclose your path in between `""`. This avoids also trouble with special characters like [`^`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html), [`(` and `)`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html), [`&`, `<`, `>` and `|`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

The quotation marks in the `set` command lines again avoid trouble with special characters; they do not become part of the variable value because they enclose the entire assignment expression. Note that this syntax requires the [command extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to be enabled, but this is the default anyway.

I recommend *not* to include the quotation marks into variable values (`set VAR="some value"`), because then you could run into problems particularly when concatenating strings due to unwanted (double-)quotation (for instance, `echo "C:\%VAR%\file.txt"` returns `"C:\"some value"\file.txt"`).

Answer (score 2):

You are perfectly right. If the path to the file you want to execute contains spaces, you have to surround it with quotation marks:

```
@echo off

set qtpath=C:\Program Files\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin
set execpath="%qtpath%\windeployqt.exe"

echo %execpath%

%execpath% --someparams
```

This should work.

It will also work when you surround `%execpath%` with quotation marks:

```
"%execpath%" --someparams
```